# How to retrieve JSON from my method?

Tags: java, json, rest

I have the following class:

```
@Path("/")
public class RESTService {

@GET
@Path("verifica")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response verificaREST(InputStream dadoRecebido) {
    String resultado = "Servico REST startou sucesso";
    return Response.status(200).entity(resultado).build();
}

@Path("multiplica:{n}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response TimesTwo(@PathParam("n") float n) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("primeiro", n);
    jsonObject.put("segundo", 2 * n);
    return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject.toString()).build();
}
```

}

When I acess http://localhost:8080/RestWithJSON/123/verificawith this I can see `Servico REST startou sucesso` . When I enter http://localhost:8080/RestWithJSON/123/multiplica:4 I can see `{"primeiro":4,"segundo":8}` on my browser. Now I'm trying to use the following client class to receive some JSON from `TimesTwo` method:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RestWithJSON/123/multiplica:24");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    System.out.println(connection.getContentType());
    System.out.println(connection.getInputStream().toString());
    System.out.println(connection.getContent());
```

But with this I only got the following:

```
application/json
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@378fd1ac
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@378fd1ac
```

So, even if my `contentType` is correct, how can I retrieve my data from JSON?

Comment: That looks like code to *send* some JSON in a POST request (though it doesn't work), not to receive a JSON response from a GET.

Comment: It looks like you're using Spring for the server, so why not use [Spring for the client too](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **read** from the `InputStream`:

```
JSONObject myData = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream(),
    connection.getContentEncoding());
```

`IOUtils`is a class from the Apache Commons IO utility library.

Answer (score 0):

You can access JSON Object in the your client application.

For that you need to use fallowing Jackson Databind dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

And you need to configure fallowing things in the `applicationContext.xml` file

```
<beans:bean -- 

<!-- To  convert JSON to Object and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean> 

</beans:bean>
```